# Expected value of colored fair die with random variable having the value k if all colors appear in first k tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a fair die with brown, black, and white colors on two of the six faces each being tossed continously (each color has two faces.) Y is the random variable having the value k if

(1) 2 of 3 colors appear in first k-1 tosses

(2) all colors appear in first k tosses.

What is E[Y]?

I think i should compute the probability of the opposite (not all colors appear in first k tosses.) There is a formula $$E[Y]=\sum_{k=0}^{infinity} P(Y>k)$$ i believe i can use. Since for k tosses, there are P(Y>k) chances that not all colors apepar in first k tosses. how can i apply this formula?

Comment: By "2 of 3 colours" do you mean "at least two" or "exactly two"?

Comment: exactly 2 i meant

Answer (score 1):

- The probability that exactly one colour has appeared in the first $k$ throws is $\dfrac{{3 \choose 1}\cdot 1^k}{3^k}$ for $k \ge 1$
- The probability that exactly two colours have appeared in the first $k$ throws is $\dfrac{{3 \choose 2}\cdot \left(2^k -  {2 \choose 1}\cdot 1^k\right)}{3^k}$ for $k \ge 1$

So adding these together and simplifying: $P(Y>k) = \dfrac{2^k - 1}{3^{k-1}}$ for $k \ge 1$ and you can do your infinite sum using geometric series

Remember that $P(Y>0)=1$

Comment: but do i need to do 1-P(Y>k) to get the P of all three colors?

Comment: what i do not understand is hwo this also satisfies the first condition 2 of 3 colors appear in first k-1 tosses

Comment: You could use $P(Y=k)=P(Y>k-1)- P(Y>k)$ and then your expectation would be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kP(Y=k)$.  But this step is unnecessary as it is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(Y>k)$, which you can see from an almost telescopic sum

Comment: $Y=k$ is the event that $k$ is the smallest number of throws by which you have all three colours: you have all three colours after $k$ throws but you did not after $k-1$ throws (obviously you must have had at least two colours if one more throw takes you to three).  So $Y>k$ is the event that after $k$ throws you do not have all three colours - you might have one or two (or if $k=0$, then none).  So the first condition is already incorporated